# Where does Chinese Windows 7 get its Chinese font names?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, chinese

How does Windows 7 map Chinese .TTF font files into the native Chinese font name? If no such info is in the actual TrueType font file?

For example: Chinese version of Windows 7 contains msyh.ttf file which is a regular Microsoft YaHei font.

Any font viewer will show this exact font name - exept Windows 7 itself. GDI font enumeration routine returns '微软雅黑' as a name.

Where does the actual mapping happen? Anyone know the mapping scheme? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As the person above said: "True type fonts have their **names** embedded inside".

I'm making my own custom font file (but I'm not a font developer), and I also able to put the names in different languages in the font file, and it (the situation) must be the same for the real font developers.

For me, I make my own font with CJK support (with differentiation for C/J/K) as a lot of program can load only one font at one time and I can't set four different fonts (for Latins, Chinese, Japanese, Korean) to load at the same time in those programs.

I can view all the names in different languages via my font editor itself.

For example, my font *Hidayat's Custom Font CJK* .
It will appear as *Hidayat's Custom Font CJK* in US/UK English Windows, appear as *喜达亚CJK字体* in Singaporean/PRC Chinese Windows, appear as *やつこ自分のCJK字体* in Japanese Windows and *Font CJK Hidayat Sendiri* in Malay Windows as I already defined those names in my font. And the font developer must have done the same thing that *微软雅黑* appeared in Chinese ver. Windows. (微软wēi ruǎn means Microsoft->微wēi is "very tiny" and 软ruǎn is "soft" and 雅黑yǎ hēi is the font name)

Well, I've said that I'm using a font editor to view the names in the "naming" part.
Look at these (my font used as the examples, IDon'tWant to violate laws!):
Naming (US English): https://puu.sh/2GaIs.png 
Naming (PRC Chinese): http://puu.sh/2GaRY.png 
Naming (Japanese):  http://puu.sh/2GaUz.png 
Naming (Singaporean Chinese): http://puu.sh/2GaXQ.png 
Naming (UK English): http://puu.sh/2GaZB.png 
Naming (Malaysian Malay): http://puu.sh/2Gb0F.png

Answer (score 3):

True type fonts have their names embedded inside.

Try this link for more info.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/fontnamefromfile.aspx

Comment: Yes, the English name is embedded, but I need the native (Chinese characters) name. Do you know where this mapping happens?

Comment: There are a number of names within the TTF file, Check out the naming table. Try this link [TTF Naming Table](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm)